# How can I forbid my email client (Mail iOS) to send email to a specific email address

Tags: email, deny

What I mean!

Iam in conflict about business or speak about a matter with someone.
Instead of sending the message to the person I speak, I send the message to the person/company that I talk about!
This is easy to be done when you are thinking about that person/company of you want to forward an email from that person/company but instead or forward select reply OR you just type the "forbidden" email address and press "send"
My question, is there any option/tool that allows me to RESTRICT/FORBID specific email addresses to send emails, even if I write them to send?
I am asking for iOS mail but you can advise if there is a tool in any other email client (gmail, outlook, windows, etc)
A lot of HUGE disasters would be avoided with such option/

Regards

Comment: Of course it's possible, but not very practical if you ever need to contact those people or companies. Huge disasters could be avoided by learning to be more careful.

Comment: There are spacecrafts that crashed after a thousands of controls. So, there are reasons that someone may set such a control to avoid even the mistake or an auto-correction during typing that could lead to unwanted results. You say however that it's possible! How can I do it and set this kind of control?